# How to find the size (length) of a video in Xamarin Forms, considering that System.IO.File is not available?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

It is said that 'System.IO.File' is not supported in Xamarin Forms. This [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7578/how-to-use-system-io-file-or-similar-for-cross-platform-projects-in-pcls) proves that. I would like to perform a multipart uploading using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html) code from AWS. I'm unable to use this line of code:

> long contentLength = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;

Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

As of Xamarin.Forms 2.3.5 .NET Standard is supported. When using .NET Standard in your project, instead of portable class libraries, you are able to use the classes from `System.IO`.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't get you. Can you be a little more specific? I changed the code to 
long contentLength = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath).Length;
but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: You have to port your portable class libraries to .NET Standard ([MSDN documentation on .NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/net-standard)) in order to use the classes.